# finding some based on checkbox and select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i am trying to find SUM of some number based on check box and select option .

here is my code

```
<div class="container">
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="10">10
</label>
</div>
<input id="total" placeholder="total" />
```

And my script is

```
function updateTotal(){
var total = 0;

 $(".container input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){    
if($(this).is(":checked")){
  var multiplier = Number($(this).parent().prev().val());
  var checkboxAmount = Number($(this).val());

  total += multiplier * checkboxAmount;
   }
 });

$("#total").val(total);
```

}

$("select, input[type='checkbox']").on("change", updateTotal);

The above script is just working fine give html code . But when keep my checkbox first and select option next , then this script will not give any output

i wanted my HTML code like this , then script should be work fine for this

```
<div class="container">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="10">10
</label>
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</div>
<input id="total" placeholder="total" />
```

any help , [code coppied from here](https://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/m3u5ovty/)

Comment: It looks like you moved the checkbox to before the options so `.parent().prev()` is no longer valid as the options are after it.  You could try changing prev() to next().  However, I would highly suggest you look into using some form of `closest(parentSelector).find('select')` instead so it doesn't matter the sibling positions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-

```
function updateTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".container").each(function () {
    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    var select = $(this).find("select");
    if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
      total += Number($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").val()) * Number(select.val());
    }
  });
}
```